# Пропало главное меню в Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Установил себе Visual Studio 2015. Запустил. А главного верхнего меню нету. Поэтому не могу зайти не в какие настройки. Пробивал несколько раз перестанавливать Visual Studio 2015 (Enterprise и Community). Но результат тот же.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто-то знает в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Установил себе Visual Studio 2013. Там все нормально работает. Но все таки хотелось бы, чтоб работала нормально Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Расширение какое-то, вероятно, установили. Попробуйте нажать `Alt`, находясь в студии.

Comment: Вот это случайно не устанавливали? https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bdbcffca-32a6-4034-8e89-c31b86ad4813 Но как сказал @ixSci, `Alt` должен показать главное меню.

Comment: При нажатие Alt меню появилось. Спасибо за помощь! Раз 5 перестанавливал Visual Studio, лазал в реестре, а надо было всего лишь нажать одну клавишу.

Comment: @andreycha Действительно обнаружил у Visual Studio дополнение **"Hide Main Menu"**. Правда я его не устанавливал. Возможно оно почему то по-умолчанию установилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря помощи [@andreycha](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/106/andreycha) узнал, что во всем виновато дополнение [Hide Main Menu](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bdbcffca-32a6-4034-8e89-c31b86ad4813). Меню можно отобразить при нажатие клавиши `Alt`. Но я просто удалил это дополнение из-за ненадобности.